# How to identify a series of Longitude and Latitude coordinates for a building?

Tags: gps, latitude-longitude

I have hundreds to thousands rows of data that includes the GPS coordinates of the specific location (includes building footprint and outside the building within the property survey boundaries as well as off the property boundaries) that an employee completed a task using a handheld device with GPS technology. Currently, to determine which GPS coordinates are within the building footprint or property survey boudaries, I have to copy and paste to an application such as google maps to identify the address.

So far I have found answers to how to calculate the midpoint in a series of GPS coordinates. However, I am trying to figure out how to identify which series of GPS coordinates are within a specific building footprint and property survey boundary using the "offifical" GPS coordinates of the address. By official, I mean GPS coordinates of the location when I input the address of the building in an application that provides the GPS coordinates, which I will use as the midpoint.

Can someone help me figure out how to either calculate or identify which GPS coordinates in my data are within the building footprint and/or property survey boundary from the midpoint?

Comment: Well it can actually have infinite coordinate pairs if you restrict it to say, the building footprint. ;) In practicality though, it depends on how tight you want the resolution to be. For your application, what's the smallest value at which you would consider a pair the same -- 1ft? 10m?

Comment: It sounds like he's asking for the "range" of coordinates, so the minimum bounding box. However, what software are you using, what type of data do you have?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.

Comment: do you have access to a cadastral (property boundaries) dataset for the area? are the building footprints in the form of GPS waypoints, lines or polygons?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have polygon data that represents the footprint of the house and a polygon that represents the property boundary how are going to say if your GPS data is in the building or outside it if all you have is nothing other than this "official" GPS coordinate?

I would also be *highly* sceptical of a GPS coordinate from a handheld GPS claiming to be inside a building as they don't work well under those scenarios. Yes you *may* get a signal but it could potentially be many metres out.

You do not state your GIS system you are using or any restrictions such as license level (you should *always* state these in your question). I will assume you are using ArcGIS, in that case you can run the [NEAR](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/near.htm#L_) tool to assign the ID of the official GPS coordinate to your points.

Finally you talk about GPS coordinates, it would be sensible to project your data into a national grid or other local coordinate system so you are measuring in metres rather than decimal degrees.